# Variable assigned to HTML input's value through PHP is not understood by JS script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, charts

I'm working on a project of a website which shows a chart. User should be able to change a displayed chart (without changing the website) by clicking one of 'Available sensors' from dropdown options. Dropdown connects to MySQL database with used sensors. The sensor's id is assigned to HTML-input ID and its name is assigned to input value.

My intension is to use sensor ID in another *data.php* file which is responsible for connecting to tables (MySQL) with data collected by sensors. This ID would tell to which of the tables this programm should connect.

At the moment JS script's task is to alert an ID of the chosen sensor when it's clicked on the dropdown menu. Instead of a number I get a message saying 'undefined'. Eventually it would transfer the stored id to the mentioned data.php file.

Could you please tell me whether it's necessary to use AJAX in this case or what's a possible reason of this error in my code?

I also tried to use button insted of input. When clicking on sensors names on dropdown I've received only messages with '1'. However assigning `sensorName` worked out in both cases. Sensors ID is stored as INT, name as VARCHAR in MySQL table.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

```
<div id="header_btn" class="dropdown">

    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Available sensors" class="btn btn-success" />

    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <?php
            include("config.php");
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM sensors";
            $result = $db->query($sql);

            if($result->num_rows > 0){
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    $sensorID = $row["id"];
                    $sensorName = $row["WebName"];
        ?>
                <input onclick="changeSensorID(this.value)" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'" class="btn_drop" id="<?php echo $sensorID ?>" value="<?php echo $sensorName ?>" /></a>
        <?php
                }
            }
        ?>

    </div>
    <script>
        function changeSensorID() {
            var sensorID = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_drop").id;
            alert(sensorID);
        };
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("btn_drop")` returns multiple element not just one. You'll have to use something like `document.getElementsByClassName("btn_drop")[0].id`

Comment: I've changed my code and it shows again message with '1' for each sensor. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check this code, working fine

```
            <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Available sensors" class="btn btn-success" />

            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <?php
                    include("config.php");
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sensors";
                    $result = $db->query($sql);

                    if($result->num_rows > 0){
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                            $sensorID = $row["id"];
                            $sensorName = $row["WebName"];
                ?><input onclick="changeSensorID(event)" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'"
                                onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'" class="btn_drop" id="<?php echo $sensorID ?>"
                                value="<?php echo $sensorName ?>" /></a>


                        <?php
                        }
                    }
                        ?>

            </div>
           <script >
                function changeSensorID(event){
                    var sensorID = event.target.id;
                    alert(sensorID);
                }
            </script>


        </div>
```

Comment: In case of any issue, please post here i will catch you soon

Comment: Please add an explanation, what you've changed and why it does solve the problem.

Comment: Your syntax to get the ID is wrong.
        var sensorID = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_drop").id;
To do this easy i used the event based JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns array of at least one item if found any. You have to provide index of element that you want to use.

## Example

```
var sensorID = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_drop")[0].id;
```